# Which meaning does Singular Value Decomposition without centering have?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

I'am trying to understand Singular Value Decomposition(SVD) fully.

I know that when we do PCA, we usually do centering(subtracting mean) to build a covariance matrix.

Regardless above, I want to understand the meaning of SVD of matrix of size (m,n) without centering.

In my gut feeling, this will also quite catch the principle component of matrix without centering, but not sure for this is correct.

Is there any intuition about SVD of raw (m,n) data matrix?

Comment: Correllation instead of Covariance?

Comment: @mathreadler, Why do you think it is correlation? Do you have any explanation of your rationale?

Comment: I think a short wikipedia tour should clear it out but I am afraid I don't have the time to write an answer.

Comment: It is enough just tossing a reference link for me!

Comment: The closest link I can think of is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix I assume you have probably already read about SVD on wikipedia.